# Image is not showing in PDF when converting from html in phantom-html2pdf

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs, html2pdf

I am trying to convert my html file to PDF using phantom-html2pdf. My html code is.

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<style>
p.serif {
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}

p.sansserif {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
#i{

font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;;
}

#h{
font-family: Papyrus;}
#l{
font-family: 'Shadows Into Light', cursive;}
#s{
font-family: 'Sigmar One', cursive;}
#o{
font-family: 'Orbitron', sans-serif;}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c9/Moon.jpg"  style="width:304px;height:228px;">
<h1>CSS font-family</h1>
<p class="serif">This is a paragraph, shown in the Times New Roman font.</p>
<p class="sansserif">This is a paragraph, shown in the Arial font.</p>
<div id="i">a quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog </div>
<div id="h">a quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</div> 
<div id="l">a quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</div> 
<div>a quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</div> 
<div id="s">a quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</div> 

</body>

</html>
```

I want to convert the same html in PDF using phantom-html2pdf using node module
the code is

```js
var pdf = require('phantom-html2pdf');
var options = {
    "html" : "b.html",
    "css" : "style.css",
    "paperSize":{ format: 'Letter', orientation: 'portrait', border: '1cm' }};
  /*  "js" : "Path to additional JavaScript file",
    "runnings" : "Path to runnings file. Check further below for explanation.",
    "deleteOnAction" : true/false (Deletes the created temp file once you access it via toBuffer() or toFile()) */

 pdf.convert(options, function(result) {

    /* Using a buffer and callback */
    result.toBuffer(function(returnedBuffer) {});

    /* Using a readable stream */
    var stream = result.toStream();

    /* Using the temp file path */
    var tmpPath = result.getTmpPath();

    /* Using the file writer and callback */
   result.toFile(id[0]+'.pdf', function() {console.log(tmpPath)});
});
```

but the image is not showing in PDF. How to give images to show in PDF.
Is there any other option to convert html file to PDF?

Comment: Could be the ssl issue, try it with --ssl-protocol=any and see if that helps.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply,
can you please give some code for calling the protocal  in my code

Comment: That's a command line option to phantomjs

Comment: even i tried to convert local image . but it is not converting in pdf

Answer (score 1):

I used the full path of the image. 
For example:

```
<img src="file:///Users/linden/Desktop/earth.jpg" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, I have added an image to the PDF while converting both HTML and ejs by referring to the following,

[proto-node-pdf](https://github.com/Corgi-IT/proto-node-pdf)